# Error publishing info-path form 2013 in share point 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, error

When I publish info-path form 2013 on site collection in SharePoint 2013 I see the following error.

[image: when publish Error]

And does not publish.

Do you have an idea?

Thanks!

Comment: I found the answer to my question.This issue occurs because the Desktop Experience feature is not enabled on the Windows Server 2012. Therefore, connections cannot be made from the Windows Server 2012 to the SharePoint server. So we have to activate it.